# Couldn't install neovim on WSL-Debian because of unmet dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

on my WSL-debian,

```
$ uname -a
Linux BlahBlah 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I couldn't install neovim from apt (`sudo apt install neovim`) because unmet dependencies triggered by `ncurses-base`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ncurses-base : Breaks: neovim (< 0.6.0) but 0.4.4-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Is there a way to fix it?

---

According to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel), I should check `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` to locate some broken packages but I don't even have this log file in the system so I assume there is currently no broken package.

```
$ apt show ncurses-base
Package: ncurses-base
Version: 6.4-4
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Essential: yes
Section: misc
Source: ncurses
Maintainer: Craig Small <csmall@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 388 kB
Provides: ncurses-runtime
Breaks: bash-static (<< 4.4.18-1.1), libmono-corlib4.5-cil (<< 4.6.2.7+dfsg-2), libslang2 (<< 2.3.1a-3), libtinfo5 (<< 6.1), libunibilium0 (<< 2), libunibilium4 (<< 2.0.0-3), neovim (<< 0.6.0), vim-common (<< 2:9.0.1000-2), zsh-static (<< 5.4.2-4)
Homepage: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: basic terminal type definitions
 The ncurses library routines are a terminal-independent method of
 updating character screens with reasonable optimization.
 .
 This package contains terminfo data files to support the most common types of
 terminal, including ansi, dumb, linux, rxvt, screen, sun, vt100, vt102, vt220,
 vt52, and xterm.
```

Comment: do you have any *held packages*?

Comment: @JaromandaX description updated.

Comment: I didn't ask about *broken*, I asked do you have any *held packages* - like the error suggests *may* be the cause of the error?

Comment: @JaromandaX `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` gave me nothing

Comment: I guess you need to find out why you have an incompatible version of `ncurses-base` - what's the output of `apt show ncurses-base` (specifically the `Version`)

Comment: @JaromandaX upated